# apply output vector from function to original dataframe

Tags: r, function, dataframe, apply

I have (a few rows of) the dataframe below:

```
dput(DATA)
structure(list(S = c(12, 12, 12, 15, 15, 9), UG = c(100, 124, 
84, 108, 124, 108), N_b = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5), A = c(-12, -12, 
-12, -15, -15, -9), x.sqr = c(1440, 1440, 1440, 2250, 2250, 810
), e_1 = c(21.8, 21.8, 21.8, 29, 29, 14.6), e_2 = c(9.8, 9.8, 
9.8, 17, 17, 2.6), e_3 = c(-2.2, -2.2, -2.2, 5, 5, -9.4), e_4 = c(-14.2, 
-14.2, -14.2, -7, -7, 0), e_5 = c(0, 0, 0, -19, -19, 0), Lanes = c(3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3), m = c(0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85), 
stiff.girder = c(1468.26598316295, 1839.67918718373, 
1243.17197319875, 1828.80171434252, 2067.33917075424, 1417.62382417312) 
stiff.deck = c(911061.349082292, 2001537.86958229, 477657.265415625, 
630455.156416, 1035790.97653333, 2846237.15553796)), row.names = c(1L, 
40L, 50L, 80L, 100L, 150L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to write a function that calculates:

```
R2 <- function(x) { 
  N_b <- x["N_b"]
  N_l <- x["Lanes"]
  A <- x["A"]
  x.sqr <- x["x.sqr"]
  m <- x["m"]
  stiff.girder <-x["stiff.girder"]
  stiff.beam <- x["stiff.deck"]
  e <- x[grepl("e_\\d",names(x))]  
  f <- m * ((N_l/N_b) + (max(A * combn(e,N_l,sum)) / x.sqr) * 
                        ((252*stiff.girder/stiff.beam)^1.304))
  c(val = max(f))
}
```

But when I try to apply this to the dataframe, it creates multiple columns instead of the one that I am trying to ask for.

```
DATA <- cbind(DATA, vars = t(apply(DATA, 1, R2)))
```

Comment: remove the transpose `t()` and it should be fine

Comment: Amazing! Can you give me an explanation of why? @DanY

Comment: Vectors are treated like column vectors in R.  Even though when you print them to the screen they look like row vectors (that's just to save space when printing).  So when you transpose a column vector, you got a row vector, and you were adding a row vector to your data.frame - hence the extra columns.

Comment: Also `tapply` is *not* the same as `t(apply(...))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @DanY pointed out in the comment:

```
DATA <- cbind(DATA, vars = apply(DATA, 1, R2))
```